# Deserialization xml to C# class dynamically

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I am making web request to 3rd party API and want to dynamically deserialize that response to C# class. But there is a problem that in response I am getting sometimes list of object and sometimes one object.

It gives me error like already 'objectClass' is present in xml.

I know the solution is: I need to define different classes for both responses. Is there any other option that deserialize this xml using one class ?

Sample response:

```
<data listtype="objectClass" count="1">
    <objectClass>
    </objectClass>
</data>
```

In other response:

```
<data listtype="objectClass" count="2" totalcount="2" numremaining="0">
    <objectClass>
     <!-- Properties -->         
    </objectClass>
    <objectClass>
     <!-- Properties -->         
    </objectClass>
</data>
```

Class:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "data")]
public class Data
{

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "objectClass")]
    public objectClass ObjectItem { get; set; }    

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "objectClass")]
    public List<objectClass> ObjectItemList { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**:

At the last I found that response xml contains object name in different case.

Sample response:

```
<data listtype="objectClass" count="1">
    <objectClass>
    </objectClass>
</data>
```

In other response:

```
<data listtype="OBJECTCLASS" count="2" totalcount="2" numremaining="0">
    <OBJECTCLASS>
     <!-- Properties -->         
    </OBJECTCLASS>
    <OBJECTCLASS>
     <!-- Properties -->         
    </OBJECTCLASS>
</data>
```

I have added one more element in my data class and it works now.

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "OBJECTCLASS")]
public List<OBJECTCLASS> ObjectItem { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use the list option.
Like if you have one object, there will be one item in the list...

you can modify your class like this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "data")]
public class Data
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "objectClass")]
    public List<objectClass> ObjectItemList { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `XMLArray` and `XmlArrayItem` to help the XML deserialiser parse the objects into a `ListItems`.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "data")]
public class Data
{
    [XmlArray("data")]
    [XmlArrayItem("objectClass")]
    public List<objectClass> ObjectItemList { get; set; }
}
```